# Can two instances of tomcat running same application create same sessionId for two different users?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am working on creating shared session implementation for an application. In doing so I wanted to first understand the way tomcat (spring boot with embedded tomcat) creates Sessions for authenticated user.

I found `org.apache.catalina.util.StandardSessionIdGenerator#generateSessionId` method creates sessionid, It's uses secure random number generator and `jvmRoute` (which I have never set any where in `tomcat)`.

For the sake of this discussion if we consider `jvmRoute=""`, then this means If I run two tomcat instances behind a lb there will be collision of sessionid, but by default session affinity is enabled we will not have any issues.

But as soon as we remove session affinity we will face issues where two users can have same sessionid.

Did anyone face this issue and have resolved it?